# What is a Canadian equivalent to Sharebuilder.com?

Tags: canada, online-tools, trading, online-applications

Is there a canadian equivalent to Sharebuilder? A site which contains the same functionality, and provides the same services at roughly the same price point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Canadian ShareOwner Investments](http://www.investments.shareowner.com/home/v1/index.html) provides a similar service (i.e. scheduled buying of a select list of stocks and ETFs in dollar amounts). Price points are a bit higher, as expected. I used to have an account with them and the service was excellent.